# Downloadable products - zip files cut off at just over 1GB mark

Tags: magento-1.9, downloadable, nginx

We've had a problem with our Magento store for a long time now (used to be Magento 1.4, recently upgraded to 1.9.2) and after a few days pulling my hair out trying to find a solution without success, I thought I'd post here in case anyone has had similar problems or has any ideas what else to try.

Our Magento store sells some digital products - ranging in size from a few hundred MB to a couple of GB.

A lot of customers complain on the larger products that their downloads cut off at around the 1 gigabyte mark, and lots of testing ourselves over the last few days I've been unable to figure out the cause or a solution.   I've been testing with 1.9GB file that has caused problems for many of our customers.  (Note however that the download does not fail *every* time -- just more often than not!)

When the file is downloaded directly -- via the filesystem or a custom test .php script -- the download almost always finishes in its entirety.
When downloaded via Magento downloadable product link (testing via 'sample'), the download almost always stalls and then cuts off at around 1.08GB - 1055MB (different byte sizes each time -- have hex-inspected the end of the downloaded files and can't see any incorrect headers etc).  This is the same thing that customers report, and I can see this in the log files too -- but not everyone experiences this, and not *every* time -- just the vast majority of times!

Our Magento 1.9.2 is running on a dedicated server, running Centos with nginx.

Things that I have tried changing in order to solve this problem are:

- disabling CloudFlare (but problem occurred before I ever used CloudFlare, and persists after it is disabled)
- disabling nginx gzip support
- increasing `PHP.ini gc.max_session_lifetime` setting
- increasing `max_execution_time` setting
- set the 'sample link' to use a custom php script that uses `X-Accel-Redirect` (script downloads OK when accessed directly, but commonly fails at ~50% when used through Magento)

I've attempted to inspect the HTTP traffic to find out exactly what's going on, but have been unable to.  I also haven't been able to spot any pattern around when

When inspecting the request & response headers between the 'working' direct-download requests and the non-working Magento download requests, I can see some differences, for example:

- Magento sends `Content-Type` as `application/zip`, custom scripts send `Content-Type` as `application/octet-stream`;
- Magento sends `Expires:` header, custom scripts do not. (`Expires:` header says 1981, if that may make any difference!)
- Magento sets cookies, the custom scripts do not.
- Magento sends an `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.27` header, the custom scripts do not;
- Custom scripts send an `ETag:` header, Magento does not;

Short of attempting to implement a replacement `Downloadable` class that hands file downloads off to nginx via `X-Accel-Redirect` -- and I don't know if that would even help or just be a waste of time? -- I don't know what to try next.

If anyone has any ideas where to look, light to cast on the technologies involved - or even better if you've had this problem yourself and know how to fix it!

Comment: Have you tested another/newer PHP version? Have you tried to mute PHP error messages in index.php resp. php.ini? Just a guess... I assume you already tested different browsers... But have you used any download managers or wget or something similar? Maybe that helps zeroing in on your problem

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @Ni-Ge.  I posted a similar request on the Magento Commerce site at http://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Downloadable-files-cut-off-corrupt-at-just-over-1GB-mark/ and based on the suggestions there, I ended up implementing a simple module that uses X-Accel-Redirect to handle the downloads.  I haven't had a report of a customer complaint since, but it is still early days..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I wrote a simple Magento module that uses X-Accel-Redirect to handle the downloads (extending Mage_Downloadable_DownloadController and overriding the _processDownload function).  I haven't had a customer complain about a downloading problem since this was implemented.

Comment: Can u please tell me what change you have done at code label??